# How do I change DispatchTimeInterval to have a member milliseconds

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios13

In my code im getting a "Value of type 'DispatchTimeInterval' has no member 'millisecond'" error and i do not know how to fix it

```
var prevTime = DispatchTime.now()
let dt = prevTime.distance(to: currTime).millisecond
```

Answer (score 0):

`DispatchTimeInterval` has no instance property named `milliseconds`. It is an `enum` and has a `case` named `milliseconds`. You can add a `milliseconds` property in an extension. But since `DispatchTimeInterval` can represent an interval measured in microseconds or nanoseconds, you have to decide how you want to convert those intervals to milliseconds. It can also represent an infinite interval, and you have to decide how to convert that to milliseconds.

Here is a simple implementation that rounds micros and nanos toward zero, and returns `Int.max` for the infinite interval:

```
extension DispatchTimeInterval {
    var milliseconds: Int {
        switch self {
        case .seconds(let s): return s * 1_000
        case .milliseconds(let ms): return ms
        case .microseconds(let us): return us / 1_000 // rounds toward zero
        case .nanoseconds(let ns): return ns / 1_000_000 // rounds toward zero
        case .never: return .max
        }
    }
}
```

You could instead round to nearest and return `nil` for the infinite interval:

```
extension DispatchTimeInterval {
    var milliseconds: Int? {
        switch self {
        case .seconds(let s): return s * 1_000
        case .milliseconds(let ms): return ms
        case .microseconds(let us): return (us + 500) / 1_000
        case .nanoseconds(let ns): return (ns + 500_000) / 1_000_000
        case .never: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i fixed this, get a new error "let dTheta = myData.rotationRate.y * dt" saying "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int?'". How should I fix it.